# Subscribe to S3 bucket notifications SNS Topic directly on EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns, aws-cli

I'd like to subscribe to a S3 bucket notifications SNS Topic directly on an EC2 instance where I have a script running that's listening for a S3 bucket update event.

I assume I need to do:

```
aws sns subscribe --topic-arn [ARN of S3 bucket update topic] --protocol [email, email-json, http, https, or sqs]
```

What protocol would make sense in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, you would need to have an endpoint on your ec2 instance that can receive and process the messages from SNS so the protocol would be `http` or `https` (depending how you setup the server on your ec2 instance). You can read more about this in [Sending Amazon SNS Messages to HTTP/HTTPS Endpoints](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToHttp.html)

Note sure how you wrote your script but if its using python/java/javascript or anything that can be supported by lambda it would be much better to deploy your code in a lambda function and have the message sent to this lambda, you only pay when its executed (in the other case, your ec2 instance needs to be always up and running to listen to messages). `lambda` is a supported protocol of sns subscription

A third option is to introduce SQS in the picture, you will run in asynchronous mode (depends on your requirement if its an option or not)
you would choose `sqs` as the protocol value of your SNS message (read [Sending Amazon SNS Messages to Amazon SQS Queues](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToSQS.html) for more info) and you would need your ec2 webservice to pick the message in sqs queue

Comment: thanks. The reason for the EC2 (rather than Lambda) is because I have a web service running continuously on the EC2 instance, and the need to subscribe to the S3 bucket update event is so that so the script (it doesn't exist yet but it will probably be a bash or python script) can download the updated file from S3.

Comment: Regarding what you said in the first part of your answer "need to have an endpoint on your ec2 instance that can receive and process the messages from SNS", could you please elaborate a bit? By endpoint, do you mean I need to be running a separate server on my EC2 instance purely to provide a way to receive HTTP/S messages from SNS?

Ideally, I want to avoid that if possible. All I need is for my script to subscribe to SNS events, and then listen for an event when the S3 bucket is updated. Is there no simple way to do so? Can SQS help here?

Comment: when using http/s protocol for sns subscription, you need to have an endpoint available (in your case on your ec2 instance) that is able to treat the HTTP POST request used by sns (you can read more in the link I provided) If your web service can do that already, it can be ok

Comment: you can put sqs in picture too if you dont want to have an endpoint directly on your ec2 instance. you would choose `sqs` as the protocol value of your SNS message (read [Sending Amazon SNS Messages to Amazon SQS Queues](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToSQS.html) for more info) and you would need your ec2 webservice to pick the message in sqs queue.

Comment: It depends what kind of system you are building, if you have the http/s protocol you're building a synchronous system so you have a change in s3, sns directly send it to your ec2 endpoint and you treat it. with SQS in picture you are asynchronous mode, update in s3, message put in queue, then the queue will be treated. there are pros and cons, you need to decide depending your requirements

Comment: many thanks for clarifying. Yes, what I need is the asynch mode of operation, which means SQS seems to be the way to proceed. Would you like to update your answer so I can then mark it as answering my question? Cheers!